# SP2010: Trigger Email on Attachment Addition

Tags: 2010, workflow, custom-list, email, attachments

I've a custom list and it has a people picker column 'A'. I want to send an email to the person in column 'A' if someone attaches a file to the list item. How can this be achieved without using SPD?

Comment: you want to achive your requirment without using SPD.M I right then you can use Event handler (C# code)

Answer (score 1):

In SPD, you can create a new workflow on your list. Starting option will be on item updated (can be on item added too). Set a condition like : If **current item : attachment file** is **yes**, then send email to **current item : column A : email**.

You can also add in email body a link to **current item : attachment file**.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send email without using SPD, then there is another approach is **Event Handler**

- Item Added event
- Item Updated event

  ```
  public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
  {
      base.ItemAdded(properties);
      using (SPSite site = properties.OpenWeb().Site)
      {
          using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
          {


          var attachments=properties.ListItem["Attachments"]

  #Check current item has attahments or not.If yes then send email
          if(attachments != null)
          {
          #write logic to send Email 
          }
      }
  }


  public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
  {
      base.ItemAdded(properties);
      using (SPSite site = properties.OpenWeb().Site)
      {
          using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
          {

          var attachments=properties.ListItem["Attachments"]
          #Check current item has attahments or not.If yes then send email
          if(attachments != null)
          {
          #write logic to send Email 
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this using javascript/jquery?

Comment: Yes, only when,If you have custom button to add/Update items in list. But if you are using default behavior of SharePoint list for add/update, then it is not possible using javascripts/jquery, in javascript you will not able to get the event item added/ item updated. I will suggest stick with the above suggest approach from answer